# Barcode Scanning Via Mobile Browser?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, barcode-scanner

I am looking at trying to scan barcodes from a mobile device.

I been doing some research and I having hard time finding JavaScript libraries that can do this.

I see these projects

[zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

This seems to be no longer in development and just bugs fixes are done?

[QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/)

This one, I am not sure if it is development either anymore as changelog is from 2017

[quagga2](https://github.com/ericblade/quagga2)

This seems to be a fork of the one above? So this might be the better choice to go with vs the 2?

What I am trying to achieve is this. I want to go on an andriod device (think phone, maybe tablet), load up chrome or firefox, go to my site click a button and load up the devices camera and scan a bar code (mostly EAN-8/13).

I want to do the same thing on apple devices (iphone and ipad), load up safari (not sure if they got chrome and Firefox on these devices. I don't own apple), click a button and load up their devices cameras and scan a bar code.

I think this is possible in all the libraries I listed above, but I am still unclear if this is possible on apple devices? I read somewhere that before ios 14 it would not be possible?

I am open to other libaries, I can use Jquery, vanilla javascript and I think angular (but I think it is version 3).

Comment: FYI https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/ (based on zxing-js)

Answer (score 2):

Just been doing this same research myself. All of those open source ones you listed seem to be either dead or have performance/reliability issues. Looks like only the commercial versions are really viable at the moment:

- Dynamsoft - https://www.dynamsoft.com/store/dynamsoft-barcode-reader/
- Scanbot - https://scanbot.io/products/barcode-software/web-barcode-scanner/

There are also two different mobile apps that are viable. These are web apps that just display a browser view and make a barcode scanning function from the app itself available on the page:

- https://berrywing.com/scan-to-web-app/
- https://www.mochasoft.dk/iphone_barcode2.htm

The second one has a more capable JS API of the two.

UPDATE: I went with that last option from Mochasoft. Turned out quite well.

Comment: Another commercial app is scandit.io. I released a new version of my self written scanner browser today: https://github.com/Adrianotiger/qr2web 
But I have to update the source code.

Answer (score 1):

There's an experimental barcode scanner API now, that doesn't require any external library: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Barcode_Detection_API

Chrome Web View on Android supports it.

```
const barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector({
    formats: ["ean_8", "ean_13"],
});

barcodeDetector
    .detect(imageEl)
    .then((barcodes) => {
        barcodes.forEach((barcode) => console.log(barcode.rawValue));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on David's answer, I would like to add [STRICH](https://strich.io) to the list of candidates. It is a JavaScript library that scan the same types of barcodes that Quagga can, but it also supports 2D matrix codes, so it's comparable to zxing-js. In addition to Quagga and zxing-js it also brings its own scanning UI for things like camera selection, turning flashlight on/off, etc. JavaScript is obviously required, also WebGL and WebAssembly which are widely supported today. It has zero dependencies so it's really easy to integrate, there's [sample code](https://github.com/topics/strich-sdk) for plain JS as well as popular web frameworks like React, Angular and Vue.

To better understand how it compares to QuaggaJS and zxing-js I've created a [detailed comparison](https://strich.io/comparison-with-oss.html), focused on scanning performance.

Disclaimer: I am the author of STRICH.